# Python, return data to constructor & methods

Tags: python

I have a question because I am lost, how do I properly return the value of `self.total` from one method so that I can use it in another method? Thank you for your help.

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = ''

    def get_a(self):
        # self.total = ''
        for unpackList in range(0, Number):
            self.total = self.total + Number[unpackList]

    def get_b(self):
         # example code
         print(self.total)`
```

where `self.total` is integer.

I am currently getting an error. I know that it is due to the fact that I am passing an empty string to `get_b` but I don't know how to fix it.

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: You need to show us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `Number`? When do you call these methods? Are you sure you call `get_a` on the *same* object before calling `get_b`? I don't see how you're getting "invalid literal" from this code, but you're inconsistently treating `Number` as an integer and later as a list, so that's going to cause problems.

Comment: You don't need to return anything. The instance attribute `total` is attached to the object, so you can access it anywhere you have a reference to the object. Your error message is entirely unrelated.

Comment: I know I should upload the code and I would love to do it but the lines are a few hundred plus, part of the code I write modular and I have no way to do it. I am making my application for a portfolio.

Comment: "Modular" means "works independently of everything else". If you're incapable of separating the pieces of your code, then what you have is definitionally the opposite of "modular".

Comment: All in all, you have now given me a lot to think about.. THX :D

Comment: sorry to vote to close your question, but it's not reproducible – closing a question isn't necessarily a bad thing – it just means that 3 users, myself included, think you're not going to be able to get meaningful answers to your question. without knowing how objects of type `One` are being instantiated, or in what order you're calling the methods `get_a` and `get_b`, people who answer your question are likely going to have to make wild guesses. a full traceback would be helpful too, or at least enough code to show us where the `ValueError` is originating from  – thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.total` variable is a string, and you add a number to it. This variable needs to store a number.

I assume that in the code you wanted to calculate the sum of all the numbers. Instead of the usual for loop, you can use the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The resulting list is passed to the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```py
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def get_a(self):
        self.total += sum([i for i in range(Number)])

    def get_b(self):
         # example code
         print(self.total)
```

Comment: I will be glad if it helps you 

Comment: `sum([i for i in range(0, Number)])` -> `sum(range(Number))`, in general `[x for x in whatever]` should just be `whatever`, or possibly, `list(whatever)`, but `[x for x in whatever]` doesn't do anything useful.